# Get return schema from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a SQL Server stored procedure, I want to query the return tables schema such that I can easily model them with C# objects. I do not want to use an ORM, instead I want to start with existing stored procedures and then query them - given their name. Is that possible, if so what does that look like?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spu_GetModelEntities
    @modelId uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        e.EntityKey
       ,e.EntityName
       ,e.TemplateUrn
    FROM dbo.vw_DimEntity e
    WHERE e.ModelId = @modelId

    SELECT
        EntityLevelName = el.LevelEntityName
       ,EntityLevelTemplateUrn =el.LevelTemplateUrn
       ,el.Level
       ,el.EntityName
       ,el.TemplateUrn
    FROM dbo.vw_DimEntityLevel el
    WHERE el.ModelId = @modelId
END;
GO
```

Given this as an example stored procedure, how would I get the return schema from the multiple selects, the columns and their types?

Comment: I'm not following. Can you explain maybe with an example? If you have a proc that returns result sets, then surely you could see the columns and types that are returned and model them from that, no?

Comment: I want to do this programmatically, not manually. Does that help?

Comment: Are you talking about [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? Really not sure what you're asking.

Comment: If you want a schema for specific tables you can query the system tables in SQL for a given table name

Comment: @Larnu, I'm not familiar with that. Can I give it a stored procedure name and have it return the tables schemas that will be returned?

Comment: It basically does "what it says on the tin". It describes the first resultset returned. So it'll tell you the details of all the columns returned from the first result set in the SP. Names, datatypes, nullability, etc, etc, etc (all described in the link above).

Comment: Ok, just tested that out. That is not working. I would need all the tables possible from the result set.

Comment: What do you mean "all the tables"? Guessing your SP's are returning more than one resultset? Examples and desired behaviour would be real useful. :)

Comment: Okay, just a min. I'll update the question - in the mean time this might be what I need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-for-object-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: My point in the first column is speaking programatically. You programatically call the proc and have it return whatever it returns. Then you, programatically, analyze the columns for type in the resulting datasets/datatables/recordsets (whatever way you are connecting things up).